# Flutter Progress_state_button - how to change button state

Tags: flutter, button, state, break, progress

I am trying to use the progress state button in flutter. From the pub.dev docs, the widget should be set up as follows

```
    Widget buildTextWithIcon() {
return ProgressButton.icon(iconedButtons: {
  ButtonState.idle: IconedButton(
      text: "Send",
      icon: Icon(Icons.send, color: Colors.white),
      color: Colors.deepPurple.shade500),
  ButtonState.loading:
      IconedButton(text: "Loading", color: Colors.deepPurple.shade700),
  ButtonState.fail: IconedButton(
      text: "Failed",
      icon: Icon(Icons.cancel, color: Colors.white),
      color: Colors.red.shade300),
  ButtonState.success: IconedButton(
      text: "Success",
      icon: Icon(
        Icons.check_circle,
        color: Colors.white,
      ),
      color: Colors.green.shade400)
}, onPressed: onPressedIconWithText, state: stateTextWithIcon);
```

}

I have a function (already written and working fine) that I want to run when the button is clicked, changing the button state to ButtonState.loading then to ButtonState.success then back to ButtonState.idle. See below the function stated on the pub.dev site.

```
    void onPressedIconWithText() {
switch (stateTextWithIcon) {
  case ButtonState.idle:
    stateTextWithIcon = ButtonState.loading;
    Future.delayed(Duration(seconds: 1), () {
      setState(() {
        stateTextWithIcon = Random.secure().nextBool()
            ? ButtonState.success
            : ButtonState.fail;
      });
    });

    break;
  case ButtonState.loading:
    break;
  case ButtonState.success:
    stateTextWithIcon = ButtonState.idle;
    break;
  case ButtonState.fail:
    stateTextWithIcon = ButtonState.idle;
    break;
}
setState(() {
  stateTextWithIcon = stateTextWithIcon;
});
```

}
}

However, I am new to coding, and have no idea at all on how to use "breaks" or to change the button state. Could anybody help with advising on how i would insert my funcion (let's say its just void runFunction() in to the above code, changing the state from idle --> loading (onPressed) --> success --. idle.

Any help would be greatly appreciated

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could use setState to update the values for stateTextWithIcon

```
  ButtonState stateTextWithIcon = ButtonState.idle;


    Widget buildTextWithIcon() {
return ProgressButton.icon(iconedButtons: {
  ButtonState.idle: IconedButton(
      text: "Send",
      icon: Icon(Icons.send, color: Colors.white),
      color: Colors.deepPurple.shade500),
  ButtonState.loading:
      IconedButton(text: "Loading", color: Colors.deepPurple.shade700),
  ButtonState.fail: IconedButton(
      text: "Failed",
      icon: Icon(Icons.cancel, color: Colors.white),
      color: Colors.red.shade300),
  ButtonState.success: IconedButton(
      text: "Success",
      icon: Icon(
        Icons.check_circle,
        color: Colors.white,
      ),
      color: Colors.green.shade400)
}, onPressed: (){
      progressButton()
},
state: stateTextWithIcon,
);
```

this is the fucntion handled by my onPressed

```
 Future progressButton() async {
    setState(() {
//sets the  state of stateTextWithIcon to loading once button is pressed
    stateTextWithIcon = ButtonState.loading;
    });
    var url = 'https://google.com';
      final response = await http.get(url);

      if (response.statusCode == 200 || response.statusCode == 201) {
        setState(() {
//sets the  state of stateTextWithIcon to success if whatever request made was successful
          stateTextWithIcon= ButtonState.success;
        });
      } else {
        setState(() {
//sets the  state of stateTextWithIcon to fail if the request was unsuccessful
        stateTextWithIcon = ButtonState.fail;
        });
      }
  }
```

Comment: Ask more questions if you still don't understand